# How do I fetch publication-keywords via API/OAI/FTP from open Access journals ? PubMed or DOAJ or any other platform?

Tags: api, journal, pubmed, openaccess, oai

Is there a known API or any method to fetch the "author listed keywords" for all publications in [DOAJ.org](http://doaj.org) or [PMC open access subset](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/tools/openftlist/) ?

I tried the ftp of [PMC open access subset](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/tools/openftlist/) but the XML files only have IDs, abstract, title, author and affiliations as the metadata to any article. I am looking to mass fetch the keywords too listed with each publication.

Also, I saw few threads around the same but still haven't found the answer I was looking for. So have made a new post.

Any help is much much appreciated.

Thanks,

Asmi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both platforms have OAI-PMH interfaces:

http://doaj.org/oai.article?verb=Identify

http://www.pubmedcentral.nih.gov/oai/oai.cgi?verb=Identify

DOAJ seems to provide keywords in the `dc:subject` field of its output in the `oai_dc` format. PubMedCentral provides them in their `pmc` format, in their `<kwd-group/>` tag.

Just use an OAI-PMH client library in your favourite programming language. You can find some here:
https://www.openarchives.org/pmh/tools/tools.php